# Some postgress connections timing-out while others don't

Tags: laravel, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS EC2 machine running a Laravel 5.2 application that connects to a Postgress 9.6 databse running in RDS. While most of the connections work, some of them are getting rejected when trying to stablish, which causes a Timeout and consequently an error in my API. I don't know what is causing them to be rejected. Also, it is very random when it happens, when it does happen it may be in any API endpoint and inside the endpoint in any query.

When the timeout is handled by PHP, it shows a message like:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: ...)
```

Sometimes the Nginx handles the timeout and replies with a 504 Error. When Nginx handles the timeout I get an error like:

```
2019/04/24 09:48:18 [error] 20657#20657: *3236 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: {client-ip-here}, server: {my-url-here}, request: "GET {my-endpoint-here} HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "{}", referrer: "https://app.cartoriovirtual.com/"
```

All usage charts on the RDS and EC2 seems ok, I have plenty of RAM, storage, CPU and available connections for RDS. I also checked inner VPC Flows and they seem alright, however I have many IPs (listed as attackers) scanning my network interfaces, most of them been rejected. Some (to port 22) accepted but stoped at authentication, I use a `.pem` Key File for auth.

The RDS network interface only accepts requests from inner VPC machines. In its logs, every 5 minutes I have a Checkpoint like this:

```
2019-04-25 01:05:29 UTC::@:[22595]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2019-04-25 01:05:34 UTC::@:[22595]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 43 buffers (0.1%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=4.393 s, sync=0.001 s, total=4.404 s; sync files=19, longest=0.001 s, average=0.000 s; distance=16515 kB, estimate=16515 kB
```

Anyone has tips on how to find a solution? I looked at all possible logs that came in mind, fixed a few little issues but the error persists. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Perhaps security group inbound rules should be broader?

Comment: Are you sure the timeouts are what you think they are? My guess is that you have SQL queries that take too long to execute and PHP gives up on them and says the query timed out. Ruby on Rails sets the default timeout to 5 seconds. That log line seems like a query took 4.4 seconds. Can you try executing the query yourself and see how long it takes? Also, do you know if have an execution timeout set? (Disclaimer: I’m not familiar with Laravel.)

Comment: @jspcal I set free traffic inside the VPC, now EC2 and RDS can comunicante freely, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Nate, there is a execution timeout of 30s. However, the same queries are executed most of the times, with the same parameters. Just a small percentage of them gets timed out, these ones are randomly picked among the queries. I thought about concurrent blocks, but seems pgsql can handle concurrent selects in the same table just fine. Finally, I had a middleware logging the time of all executed queries during a few days. None went over 3s, and the majority of them were under 500ms.